# Running go2xunit with a container on jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, go

I am trying to running tests on Jenkinspipeline within a container. 
where its unable to find one of the binaries
`/bin/sh: line 2: go2xunit: command not found`

Snippet of jenkins test stage :

```
    stage('Tests') {

  steps {
    // NOTE: you must include '|| :' so a failed test does not prevent the
    // junit XML collection from running; any failed tests in the XML will
    // mark the build as UNSTABLE and indicate failed tests in GHE and jenkins
    sh 'make -f Makefile.release test'
    junit 'test/*xml'
  }
}
```

Makefile.release

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    @docker run -it -v test:/src/test --rm ${BUILDER_TAG} \
            2>&1 go test  -v -short ./... | \
            go2xunit -output test/test1.xml
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.12.7-alpine AS builder

#Disable cgo
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0

WORKDIR /src

# Packages required for project build and test
RUN apk add --no-cache git make
RUN go get \
        github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml \
        golang.org/x/lint/golint \
        github.com/axw/gocov \
        github.com/tebeka/go2xunit \
        github.com/wadey/gocovmerge

# These layers are only re-built when Go modules are updated
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download


# This layer is rebuilt when a file changes in the project directory
COPY . ./

RUN go install ./...
```

Where if I give the same commands on my local machine. Or if I run those commands from within the container it works well.

```
 C02X37E2JG5J:push3 auser03$ docker run -it d919c2f58e74 /bin/sh
/src # make -f makefile.release test
```

What could I be missing here.

Comment: I suspect the docker run is running up to the pipe then `go2xunit` is running on the agent. You didn't show how agent section in your Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 1):

You have to download go2x as direct dependency before running 'go2xunit' command.

```
go get github.com/tebeka/go2xunit
go test -v .\... | $(GOPATH)/bin/go2xunit -output test_report.xml
```